# How do i increment an int variable based on a change in calendar month

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a named string variable that I want to increment by 1 whenever they is a change in the calendar month. I have initialized the variable to 52 and what I want is that suppose date changes from 01/08/2019 to 01/09/2019 then the value increments to 53, date changes from 01/09/2019 to 01/10/2019 the value increments to 54 and so on. When I attempt the same using a do while loop as below I get exception;

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.DateTime' to bool

```
string fileId = "52";
var now = DateTime.Now;
var firstDayCurrentMonth = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, 1);

while (firstDayCurrentMonth.AddMonths(1))
{
     int currentId = Convert.ToInt32(fileId) + 1; 
}
```

Any suggestions on how I can get the check correct such that the variable increases by whenever the month changes? How can I retrieve the current value of fileId because I figure my implementation is also retrieving 52 on each change.

Comment: `AddMonths` returns a `DateTime`, not a `bool`. That's exactly what the compiler error tells you. You can only use a `bool`-returning expression in a `while` loop's condition.

Comment: Strings do not increment.  Use and integer and convert to string at the time and place you need a string

Comment: @dymanoid Acknowledged but how then can i check when a month has been added to the date instance now

Comment: Use the property Month.

firstDayCurrentMonth.Month will return you the month in integer. Now you can compare to Now.Month.

Just have a look in microsoft's reference.

Comment: Do you have a target DateTime for the comparison? Something like `var targetDate = firstDayCurrentMonth.AddMonths(3); while (firstDayCurrentMonth < targetDate) { firstDayCurrentMonth = firstDayCurrentMonth.AddMonths(1); currentFileId += 1; } fileId = currentFileId.ToString();`, maybe (`currentFileId` is an `int`, declared outside the loop, initialized to `fileId` as an int)?

Answer (score 0):

Why fileId is a string? As mentioned in the comments string do not increment - numbers do.
So I would change the declaration of

`string fileId = "52";`

to

```
int fileId = 52;
```

You can do all the increments or decrements you like such as:

```
while (firstDayCurrentMonth.AddMonths(1))
{
     int currentId = fileId++; 
}
```

If at anytime you require the value of fileId to be a string just called the `ToString()` method.`fileId.ToString();`